Conversion of Syslogs to Json
from __future__ import print_function
import base64
import json
import re
print('Loading function')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []
    succeeded_record_cnt = 0
    failed_record_cnt = 0
    print(event)
    for record in event['records']:   
        print(record['recordId'])
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])
        regex_string = (r"^((?:\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?"
                        r"|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b\s+(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])\s+"
                        r"(?:(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:\.,][0-9]+)?)))) (?:<(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+)> )"
                        r"?((?:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)) ([\w\._/%-]+)(?:\[((?:[1-9][0-9]*))\])?: (.*)")
        p = re.compile(regex_string)
        payload = payload.decode('utf-8')
        m = p.match(payload)
        print(p)
        print(payload)
        print(m)
        if m:
            succeeded_record_cnt += 1
            data_field = {
                'timestamp': m.group(1),
                'hostname': m.group(2),
                'program': m.group(3),
                'processid': m.group(4),
                'message': m.group(5)
            }
            output_record = {
                'recordId': record['recordId'],
                'result': 'Ok',
                'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(data_field))
            }
        else:
            print('Parsing failed')
            failed_record_cnt += 1
            output_record = {
                'recordId': record['recordId'],
                'result': 'ProcessingFailed',
                'data': record['data']
            }
        output.append(output_record)
    print('Processing completed.  Successful records {}, Failed records {}.'.format(succeeded_record_cnt, failed_record_cnt))
    return {'records': output}

I'm getting the syslogs data that need to convert to json. but i'm getting Parsing failed when i used this code.
when i check the script it is filtering by month and years but do need this how to replace this one, I need all the data from the syslog to json
regex_string
